# How to set the part of the text view between @ and alphanumeric (same as telegram user) is clickable in android java?

Tags: java, android

I want to convert the part of a string (textview) that contains the username to clickable and after the user clicks, move it to the same user's profile page (like messengers like Telegram)
For example :
My username in Telegram is @Khapez

I'm going to make Khapez clickable

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/armcha/AutoLinkTextView) is a good library for it.  The result of that library is below:

[image]

Comment: Hello my good friend
Thank you for your answer.
it was useful
But the problem is that all the links are red and can not be changed.
Even using document commands and tips

Comment: Why can't you? Try this code:`autoLinkTextView.setMentionModeColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.yourColor));
`

Comment: you're right.
Unfortunately, I wrote the line of code to adjust the text (setText) before changing the color, which was correct.